# "TypeError: get_screenshot_as_file() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)" when using Selenium to take screenshots

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium webdriver to take a screenshot of a given link but I am met with the following error

```
browser.get_screenshot_as_file()
TypeError: get_screenshot_as_file() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

The block of code I am using is

```
link = comment.permalink
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(link)
browser.get_screenshot_as_file()
browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give it a file name to which it should save the screenshot:

```
browser.get_screenshot_as_file('path/to/the/file.jpg')
```

Comment: If I want them to go into a folder that is in the same folder as my script, would I just put, for example '/Screenshot/'+link+'.png'"

Comment: You need the name of a file, so for example `./screenshot.jpg`. The leading  `.` means "the directory I am in".

Comment: Ok, so I made the changes and ran the program. I am not being met with any error, the browser opens and closes, but I am not finding the picture file anywhere

Comment: @user3518218 Try giving it an absolute path to a place you can find easily.